# Grid styles in xamarin

Tags: c#, css, xamarin, styles

I`m using css styles with xamarin forms. I`ve got grid wirh buttons:[image]

```
StackLayout {
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
    color: #ffffff;
}

Button{
    background-color: #2d2d30;
    font-family: Consolas;
    font-size: 24;

    margin: 0;
}
```

And xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    /*...*/
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    /*...*/
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button/>
    <Button/>
    /*...*/
</Grid>
```

How to remove this gaps between buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Grid {
    column-gap: 0;
    row-gap: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is inline-block elements issue. As you can see:

```css
button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  outline:none;
  border:none;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<button></button>
<button></button>
<button></button>
```

We can use these two methods to remove gaps.

1. Adjacent write

```css
button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  outline:none;
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<button></button><button></button><button></button>
```

2. Comment line

```css
button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  outline:none;
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<button></button><!--
--><button></button><!--
--><button></button>
```

Comment: Can you share all css?

Comment: it\`s all css. But I`ll add xaml

Comment: Can you add `display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap` to StackLayout

Comment: In a Button css?

Comment: it`s broke all css styles